# Can't trigger the onActivityResult method

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an issue with `onActivityResult`.

I'm using `startActivityForResult` to update some elements which data source is from a local database when these activities that I'm starting are over.

It works for two activities but, for some reason, it don't work in the last one. The statements that I put on `onActivityResult` don't trigger.

**This is the code of the first activity, which calls the others:**

```
public class ActivityEquipos extends AppCompatActivity {

public ArrayList<String> equipos = new ArrayList<>();
Spinner spEquipos;
ListView lvJugadores, lvPartidos;
Button btAddJugador, btAddPartido;
final public static int CODE_ADD_JUGADOR = 1, CODE_ADD_PARTIDO = 2, CODE_NEW_EQUIPO = 3;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_equipo, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.itNuevo:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityNewEquipo.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, CODE_NEW_EQUIPO);
            break;
        case R.id.itVolver:
            finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_equipos);

    spEquipos = findViewById(R.id.spEquipos);
    lvJugadores = findViewById(R.id.lvJugadores);
    lvPartidos = findViewById(R.id.lvPartidos);
    btAddJugador = findViewById(R.id.btAddJugador);
    btAddPartido = findViewById(R.id.btAddPartido);

    cargaSpinner();

    spEquipos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            actualizarJugadoresPartidos(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CODE_ADD_JUGADOR && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        actualizarJugadoresPartidos(spEquipos.getSelectedItemPosition());
        Toast.makeText(ActivityEquipos.this, "Jugador añadido con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == CODE_ADD_JUGADOR && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(ActivityEquipos.this, "Añadido cancelado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == CODE_ADD_PARTIDO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        actualizarJugadoresPartidos(spEquipos.getSelectedItemPosition());
        Toast.makeText(ActivityEquipos.this, "Partido añadido con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == CODE_NEW_EQUIPO && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
        Log.d("carga", "precarga");

        cargaSpinner();

        Log.d("carga", "postcarga");
        Toast.makeText(ActivityEquipos.this, "Equipo añadido con éxito.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == CODE_NEW_EQUIPO && requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(ActivityEquipos.this, "Añadido de equipo cancelado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void cargaSpinner(){
    BaloncestoSQLiteHelper helper = new BaloncestoSQLiteHelper(this, "baloncesto", null, 7);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM equipos", null);
    equipos.clear();
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            equipos.add(c.getString(0));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    spEquipos.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, equipos));

    db.close();
    helper.close();
}

private void actualizarJugadoresPartidos(int i){
    BaloncestoSQLiteHelper helper = new BaloncestoSQLiteHelper(ActivityEquipos.this, "baloncesto", null, 7);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> jugadores = new ArrayList<>();
    final Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE Nombre_equipo='" + equipos.get(i) + "'", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            jugadores.add(c.getString(1));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    ListJugadoresAdapter adapter = new ListJugadoresAdapter(ActivityEquipos.this, jugadores);
    lvJugadores.setAdapter(adapter);

    Log.d("tam", "" + jugadores.size());

    //PARTIDOS

    BaloncestoSQLiteHelper helperP = new BaloncestoSQLiteHelper(ActivityEquipos.this, "baloncesto", null, 7);
    final SQLiteDatabase dbP = helperP.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Partido> partidos = new ArrayList<>();
    final Cursor cP = dbP.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM partidos WHERE equipo_local='" + equipos.get(i) + "' OR equipo_visitante='" + equipos.get(i) + "'", null);
    if (cP.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Partido partido = new Partido(cP.getString(1), cP.getString(2), cP.getInt(3), cP.getInt(4), cP.getString(5));
            partidos.add(partido);
        } while (cP.moveToNext());
    }

    ListPartidosAdapter partidosAdapter = new ListPartidosAdapter(ActivityEquipos.this, partidos);
    lvPartidos.setAdapter(partidosAdapter);

    dbP.close();
}
```

I removed the other activity calls from the code to make easier to see with which activity I have the problem.

**Here is the second activity:**

```
public class ActivityNewEquipo extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etNombre, etConferencia, etDivision, etCiudad;
Button btAceptar, btCancelar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_equipo);

    etNombre = findViewById(R.id.etNombreEquipo);
    etConferencia = findViewById(R.id.etConferenciaEquipo);
    etDivision = findViewById(R.id.etDivisionEquipo);
    etCiudad = findViewById(R.id.etDivisionEquipo);
    btAceptar = findViewById(R.id.btAniadirEquipo);
    btCancelar = findViewById(R.id.btCancelarEquipo);

    btCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });

    btAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (etNombre.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ||
                    etCiudad.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ||
                    etConferencia.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() ||
                    etDivision.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos vacíos. Imposible introducir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                BaloncestoSQLiteHelper helper = new BaloncestoSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), "baloncesto", null, 7);
                final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("Nombre", etNombre.getText().toString().trim());
                values.put("Ciudad", etCiudad.getText().toString().trim());
                values.put("Conferencia", etConferencia.getText().toString().trim());
                values.put("Division", etDivision.getText().toString().trim());

                try{
                    db.insert("equipos", null, values);
                    db.close();
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                }catch (SQLiteConstraintException ex){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nombre de equipo duplicado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are nowhere starting ActivityNewEquipo.

Comment: Yes, I do. In the onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: Indeed. Why did not my browser find it the first  time? ;-)

Comment: Did you make sure there is no exception caught in `try` where you are using `setResult` after `db.close()`?

Comment: `Log.d("carga", "postcarga");` Do you see that log? You should put a Toast right at the first line in onActivityResult() to see if it is triggered. And then return immediately.

Comment: Yes, I tried without the try clause.

Comment: No, I don't see the Log.

Comment: ????? Which try clause? Put only one Toast() in onActivityResult(). Nothing else. Then try again. If you do not see the log then `cargaSpinner()` throws an exception which you do not catch. So again: try with only one Toast() in onActiviryResult() first.

Comment: `No, I don't see the Log.` You should have informed us too if you see `Log.d("carga", "precarga");`. Now do you? I think you do.

Comment: Nope, I still don't seeing the Log putting only the Toast without cargaSpinner()

Comment: okey, see if `requestCode == CODE_ADD_PARTIDO` fires your code without the resultCode part within the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
} else if (requestCode == CODE_NEW_EQUIPO && requestCode == RESULT_OK){
```

Change to

```
} else if (requestCode == CODE_NEW_EQUIPO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
```

And... you made that error twice!!!

If you only -as a test- had put one Toast in it only...

Comment: God, I was so tilted after hours that I didn't see this misstype. Ty so much

Comment: It took me nearly 20 minutes too to see. You should also add a last 'else' statement with a Toast() to cover all possibilities.